# How to sort a collection by multiple values AND nulls at the end using the available convenient methods of Kotlin

Tags: android, sorting, kotlin, comparator

I've used the **sortedWith** and **compareBy** methods before and it is capable of sorting using multiple parameters.

I've also used **nullsLast** method before and it is quite convenient just like the other two.

With these methods, however, I can't figure out a way to sort a collection with the following sorting rules:

Given the Class:

```java
data class MyClass(
    val varA: String?,
    val varB: String
)
```

- sort according to **varA** alphabetically and nulls/blank to be last; then
- sort according to **varB** alphabetically

So let's say I have the following collection:

```java
val collection = listOf(
    MyClass(null, "A"),
    MyClass("a", "B"),
    MyClass("c", "C"),
    MyClass("b", "D"),
    MyClass("", "E"),
    MyClass("a", "F"),
    MyClass("b", "G"),
    MyClass(null, "H"),
    MyClass("", "I")
)
```

it should then be sorted to:

```java
    MyClass("a", "B")
    MyClass("a", "F")
    MyClass("b", "D")
    MyClass("b", "G")
    MyClass("c", "C")
    MyClass(null, "A")
    MyClass("", "E")
    MyClass(null, "H")
    MyClass("", "I")
```

is there a one-liner code I can use just like the **compareBy** that uses *vararg* parameter

Comment: in the second example, you have shown, you didn't sort by the second params can you explain more.. you want to achieve the result using multiple Kotlin collection operators right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this (see [`kotlin.comparisons` documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/index.html)):

```
val comparator = compareBy<String, MyClass>(nullsLast(), { it.varA.let { if (it == "") null else it } }).thenBy { it.varB }

collection.sortedWith(comparator)
```

Comment: did you try running this code? coz it did not work for me
BUT it did lead me to the correct answer
I used `compareBy< MyClass, String?>` instead of `compareBy<String, MyClass>`

Answer (score 2):

Of course there is a one-liner for this:

```
collection.sortedBy {if(it.varA != null && it.varA.isNotEmpty()) it.varA + it.varB else "z" + it.varB}
```

Then print it:

```
output.forEach { println("Myclass(${it.varA}, ${it.varB})") }
```

Output:

```
Myclass(a, B)
Myclass(a, F)
Myclass(b, D)
Myclass(b, G)
Myclass(c, C)
Myclass(null, A)
Myclass(, E)
Myclass(null, H)
Myclass(, I)
```

**Explanation:**

We need to split the cases when we sort by `varA` and when by `varB` here. That is why there is a condition `if(it.varA != null && it.varA.isNotEmpty())`, which says that we will sort by `varA` only if its value isn't `null` or `""`.

Otherwise, we sort by string `"z" + it.varB`, which means that we sort by `varB`, **but** with `z` prefix, which will ensure that these items will be at the end of sorted collection.

To understand more easily how it works, you can try following code:

```
    val output = collection.map { if(it.varA != null && it.varA.isNotEmpty()) it.varA + it.varB else "z" + it.varB }

    output.sortedBy { it }.forEach { println(it) }
```

This one will output these strings:

```
aB
aF
bD
bG
cC
zA
zE
zH
zI
```

Now it should be more obvious. :-)

Comment: "but with z prefix, which will ensure that these items will be at the end of sorted collection" So guess what happens if you have a `Myclass("zz", "B")` (or any non-ASCII character after `z` for that matter)?

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Then you will use Char.MAX_VALUE. The "z" was for simpicity. I will add that to answer.

Comment: Ok then, the string consisting of 2 (or 1000) Char.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov Hmm, good point :D  Any idea how to make it truly generic?

Comment: The way in my answer :)